# Display offline/local image using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to know if there is the possibility to display an image in an XML that has to be uploaded in a catalog. This XML file is obtained using xslt. This image is located on my local storage.

I'm trying to use this xml code

```
<gmd:graphicOverview>
            <gmd:MD_BrowseGraphic>
                <gmd:fileName gco:nilReason="missing">
                    <gco:CharacterString> 
                       <xsl:attribute>
                         <xsl:copy-of select="/mnt/images/test_image.png"/>
                       </xsl:attribute>
                   <gco:CharacterString/>
                </gmd:fileName>
                <gmd:fileDescription>
                    <gco:CharacterString>large_thumbnail</gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:fileDescription>
            </gmd:MD_BrowseGraphic>
        </gmd:graphicOverview>
```

but it is not working. 
Is there a way to get this thumbnail in my final xml?

Answer (score 0):

The `xsl:copy-of/@select` attribute in XSLT takes an XPath (a way to specify nodes in an XML document), not a file system path.  Moreover, XML is a generic markup language and has no notion of displaying an image -- that'd be up to a specific XML application.   XML itself might provide a URL to an image or even embed the image data itself in encoded form, but "display" is not a meaningful concept at the XML level.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I will keep this on my mind

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.